# How to solve $x_{100}$ with $x_{n+1}=\frac{2x_n}{2+x_n}+1$ and $x_{1}=3$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

How to solve $x_{100}$ with $x_{n+1}=\frac{2x_n}{2+x_n}+1$ and $x_{1}=3$?

Can anybody shed light on this? regards.

Comment: Find the first few terms of the sequence and see if you can identify a pattern.

Comment: Yes. I will converges to 2. Thanks. Is there an expression for $x_{n}$?

Comment: "Solve" $\neq$ "compute."

Comment: I don't think there exists an expression for $x_n$ since trying to solve for $x_0$ leads to the statement $2x_0=2x_0+4$, thus a problem.

Comment: @SimpleArt Mathematica suggest $$a_n = \frac{2 (-1)^n +\left (-\frac{1}{4}\right)^n}{(-1)^n - \left (-\frac{1}{4}\right)^n}$$ though this is not a proof *per se*. As for $n=0$, the sequence is not defined for that -- it is indexed from 1 onward.

Comment: @ClementC. Figured that out just now!  :)  er, a simpler formula that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr:** considering a related sequence will help you obtain (very easily) the closed-form for $x_n$, from which you can plug in $n=100$ and get
$x_{100} = 2 + \frac{3}{2^{200}-1} \simeq 2 + 2\cdot 10^{-60}.$

---

**Details:** It is pretty clear that the sequence converges to $2$ *(if you do not know how to show it, prove by induction it is monotone decreasing and positive, hence convergent; and show the only possible limit is then $\ell=2$)*.

So let us consider instead the positive sequence $(a_n)_{n\geq 1}$ defined by $a_n \stackrel{\rm def}{=} x_n -2$ for all $n\geq 1$, which now converges to $0$ and satisfies the recurrence relation (from the one that $(x_n)_n$ satisfies)
$$
a_{n+1} = \frac{a_n}{a_n+4} = \frac{1}{1+\frac{4}{a_n}}, \qquad n\geq 1 \tag{1}
$$
with $a_1 = 1$.

Mmh, there are a lot of reciprocals there, and they are not that nice. Let us go further defining the (new) positive sequence $(b_n)_{n\geq 1}$ by
$b_n \stackrel{\rm def}{=} \frac{1}{a_n} = \frac{1}{x_n -2}$, so that
$$
b_{n+1} = 1+{4}{b_n}, \qquad n\geq 1 \tag{2}
$$
with $b_1 = 1$.

*This looks much nicer.* Solving this should not be too hard: there are [various standard methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving), and they will lead to
$$
b_n = \frac{4^n-1}{3}, \qquad n\geq 1
$$
from which you eventually get the closed-form expression for $x_n$:
$$
x_n = \frac{1}{b_n}+2 = \frac{3}{4^n-1}+2, \qquad n\geq 1. \tag{3}
$$
(Sanity check: it does converge to $2$, is positive, and decreasing with $x_1=3$.)

And finally: from (3), you get
$$
x_{100} = 2 + \frac{3}{2^{200}-1}.
$$

Comment: really enlightening. thanks!

Comment: My pleasure! ${}$

Answer (score 1):

By inspection, it appears that if $x_1=3=\frac31$, and $x_n=\frac{a_n}{b_n}$ where $a_n$ and $b_n$ are whole numbers, than we have,

$$a_{n+1}=4a_n-1$$

$$b_{n+1}=4b_n+1$$

Thus, we have

$$x_n=\frac{a_n}{b_n}=\frac{\frac13(2(4^n)+1)}{\frac13(4^n-1)}=\frac{2(4^n)+1}{4^n-1}$$

*used wolframalpha to calculate $a_n$ and $b_n$.

Thus, we have

$$x_{100}=\frac{2(4^{100})+1}{4^{100}-1}\approx2$$

Answer (score -1):

you are trying to find the fixed point of the function f(x)=(2x/(1+x))+1 with a derivative 2/(1+x)^2<1 on the domain [1,10],say. The fixed point is 2. you can find the term you are after by consulting any book on numerical analysis ((Mendelson's book)ang go from  there to the fixed point algorithm.

Comment: This would be better suited for a comment -- wouldn't it?